# How to run where clause on a function rather than a database column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In my `Invoice` model I am trying to fetch all outstanding invoices:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :payments

  def self.outstanding
    where("outstanding_amount != 0")
  end

  private

  def outstanding_amount
    total - payments.to_a.sum(&:amount_in_cents)
  end

end
```

This doesn't work, however, because I don't have a database column `outstanding_amount`. Is there any way to run a `where` clause on a function rather than a database field?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can pass the search conditions as an argument and let the method handle it. But in your case, wouldn't it be the same if you just put:  
`def self.outstanding
outstanding_amount == 0? ? nil : outstanding_amount
end`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the expression as part of a having clause. I'll defer to RoR wizards for the active record syntax, but your final query should amount to something like:

```
select ...
from ... join payments on ...
where ...
group by ...
having total != sum(payments.amount)
```

If most rows are imbalanced (unlikely), an alternative can be a correlated subquery:

```
select ...
from ...
where ...
and total != (select sum(amount) from payment where ...)
```

(Don't do the above if most rows are imbalanced, because performance will suck.)

A last alternative (which I'd actually recommend) is to maintain a `paid` column -- ideally, though not necessarily, using triggers. You could then use:

```
select ...
from ...
where ...
and total != paid
```

Better yet, you can rephrase the latter like:

```
where total - paid != 0
```

And then add a partial index on `(total - paid) where (total - paid != 0)`, for maximum performance.

Comment: Thanks for the nice write up. Indeed I am using a `paid` column in my invoices table right now (actually it's called `outstanding_amount` in my case). I was hoping to be able to scrap that column one day, because as you pointed out rightly, it needs to be *maintained* whenever a new invoice or payment record is saved. But you convinced me that it's probably better to keep that column. It seems there really isn't any other way to do it.

Comment: You are right, but you should spend more time on your answer and add full sql queries(without "..."). +1

Comment: @SergeyKutsko: agreed, but OP didn't provide a schema. :-)